# How can I run the Netbeans Vaadin Example project?

Tags: netbeans, vaadin

I am using NetBeans 8.2. I installed the plugin for Vaadin (version 1.30.1).  There is an option for the "Vaadin Example Project". I wanted to see that application, so I created a sample project. The IDE/plugin created 5 projects (ui, backend, parent, production, widgetset). I now want to run the project, but don't know how to do that. Which project do I need to run?

Comment: Did you run "install" with maven on root project, that will compile the widgetset? After you can start the application with "jetty:run" target on ui project. There is README.md file in root project for more instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a multi-module project. You should make a "priming build" on the top level, so that all modules are built, and then run the UI project (You can use 'jetty:run' using Maven or deploy to any servlet container).

The multi-module project generated by Vaadin archetype isn't my favourite. I'd actually suggest to start with the simpler vaadin-archetype-application archetype. If you already have a multimodule setup for your app, you can also use that archetype to create Vaadin UI module using that into existing project.